# Getting spreadsheets from Google-Drive using Perl module Net::Google::Drive::Simple

Tags: perl, google-sheets, google-drive-api

in my script I'm using perl module [`Net::Google::Drive::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Drive::Simple). I can see/download all my imported/shared files on my Google Drive, but I can't see/download any spreadsheets which I created/are shared with me.

Am I using bad module for this or are there any special methods for handling spreadsheets?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only documents like PDF or png can be downloaded directly. Google Drive Documents like spreadsheets or (text) documents need to be exported into one of the available formats. Check for "exportLinks" on a file given.

[Source](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Google::Drive::Simple#gd-download-item-local_filename)